# How to use python-poetry across architectures?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, x86-64, armv7, python-poetry

My primary development machine is `x86_64` while some of my deploy environments are `arm7vl` (Raspberry Pi).  For most Python development, this isn't a problem, but some Python libraries are are only available exclusively in [PyPI](https://pypi.org/) for `x86_64` or [piwheels](https://piwheels.org/) for `aarmv7l`.  This has lead to some difficulty using Poetry.  As a simple example, here's a `pyproject.toml` file created on the `x86_64` machine:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "poetrytest"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Your Name <you@example.com>"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"
opencv-python = "^4.5.5"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

The corresponding `poetry.lock` file contains hashes for files pulled from PyPI and when you run `poetry install` everything works as expected.  *However*, if you copy these two files over to a Raspberry Pi, the install fails to find an appropriate `.whl` file and therefore falls back to trying to build from source which takes roughly 2 hours and fails :-(

To make it work on the Pi, you need to add this block to `pyproject.toml`:

```
[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "piwheels"
url = "https://www.piwheels.org/simple/"
```

...then delete `poetry.lock` and run `poetry install`.  This will re-generate the lock file, (now with entries from piwheels.org) and install everything as expected.  However this isn't terribly useful, since it means that I can't version `pyproject.toml` or `poetry.lock`.  I also can't include the above source snippet in the original `pyproject.toml` file, or the build on the `x86_64` machine dies with `Unable to find installation candidates`.

So far, the only cross-platform way I can find to make this work is to keep everything versioned from the `x86_64` machine and just run this on the Pi when I want to install something:

```
$ poetry export --without-hashes > requirements.txt
$ pip install --requirement requirements.txt
```

which... sucks.  Surely, there must be a better way?

Comment: I guess this is not possible at the moment: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/4854

Comment: Ah!  Well that's a pity.  At least I know that this is a known problem :-(

Comment: Documentation here `https://python-poetry.org/docs/repositories/` states that you should be able to run `poetry config repositories.piwheels https://www.piwheels.org/simple/`. But ofc it doesn't fix your (our) problem

Answer (score 0):

A way around your issue could be to use conda instead of poetry. Then set the environment variable **CONDA_SUBDIR=<your_platform>**  which forces the platform to use when building the virtual environment with:

```
conda env create ...
```

(Not tested) You should then be able to transfer the created virtual environment and use it in your deploy environment.